# Regex to catch all files but those starting with "."

Tags: regex, dotfiles

In a directory with mixed content such as:

```
.afile
.anotherfile
bfile.file
bnotherfile.file
.afolder/
.anotherfolder/
bfolder/
bnotherfolder/
```

How would you catch everything *but* the files (not dirs) starting with `.`?
I have tried with a negative lookahead `^(?!\.).+?` but it doesn't seem to work right.
Please note that I would like to avoid doing it by excluding the `.` by using `[a-zA-Z< plus all other possible chars minus the dot >]`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^[^.].*$
```

`[^abc]` will match anything that is **not** a, b or c

Comment: This answer is incorrect because `.` must be escaped as `\.`. See my answer below.

Comment: I don't think the dot has special meaning with a bracket expression . . . the above works for me.

Comment: Indeed so it seems. Odd but ok.

Comment: The . does not need to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me negative classes! Takes no time to get rusty with regex;) I was going through the mythical onigoruma doc and totally missed it (http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt).
Also great to know escaping is not needed in classes.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping `.`and negating the characters that can start the name you have:

```
^[^\.].*$
```

Tested successfully with your test cases [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/).

Answer (score 1):

The negative lookahead `^(?!\.).+$` does work. Here it is in Java:

```
    String[] files = {
        ".afile",
        ".anotherfile",
        "bfile.file",
        "bnotherfile.file",
        ".afolder/",
        ".anotherfolder/",
        "bfolder/",
        "bnotherfolder/",
        "", 
    };
    for (String file : files) {
        System.out.printf("%-18s %6b%6b%n", file,
            file.matches("^(?!\\.).+$"),
            !file.startsWith(".")
        );
    }
```

The output is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/nfNAm)):

```
.afile              false false
.anotherfile        false false
bfile.file           true  true
bnotherfile.file     true  true
.afolder/           false false
.anotherfolder/     false false
bfolder/             true  true
bnotherfolder/       true  true
                    false  true
```

Note also the use of the non-regex [`String.startsWith`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29). Arguably this is the best, most readable solution, because regex is not needed anyway, and `startsWith` is `O(1)` where as the regex (at least in Java) is `O(N)`.

Note the disagreement on the blank string. If this is a possible input, and you want this to return `false`, you can write something like this:

```
!file.isEmpty() && !file.startsWith(".")
```

#### See also

- [Is regex too slow? Real life examples where simple non-regex alternative is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667015/is-regex-too-slow-real-life-examples-where-simple-non-regex-alternative-is-bette/2679869#2679869)

  - In Java, `.*` even in `Pattern.DOTALL` mode takes `O(N)` to match.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... how about a negative character class?

```
[^.]
```

to exclude the dot?