# What's faster: Regex or string operations?

Tags: c#, regex, string, performance

When should I use Regex over string operations and vice versa only regarding performance?

Comment: Simple question with a simple answer. If you want to optimise performance, then choose the option that performs better.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## It depends

Although string manipulation will usually be somewhat faster, the actual performance heavily depends on a number of factors, including:

- How many times you parse the regex
- How cleverly you write your string code
- Whether the regex is precompiled

As the regex gets more complicated, it will take much more effort and complexity to write equivalent string manipulation code that performs well.

Comment: Regular expressions are slow when they require _backtracking_ to parse. For example, if the regular expression `(.*)(,)` sees a comma, should that be considered part of the first group or second group? It could be either; if one parse fails later on, the RegEx engine has to backtrack and try again with the other parse. On the other hand `([^,]*)(,)` would require the comma to be part of the second group without looking ahead. See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2670853/1078199

Answer (score 33):

String operations will always be faster than regular expression operations. Unless, of course, you write the string operations in an inefficient way.

Regular expressions have to be parsed, and code generated to perform the operation using string operations. At best, the regular expression operation can do what's optimal to do the string manipulations.

Regular expressions are not used because they can do anything faster than plain string operations, it's used because it can do very complicated operations with little code, with reasonably small overhead.

Answer (score 17):

I've done some benchmarks with two functions called FunctionOne (string operations) and FunctionTwo (Regex). They should both get all matches between '<' and '>'.

**benchmark #1:**

- times called: 1'000'000
- input: 80 characters
- duration (string operations // FunctionOne): 1.12 sec
- duration (regex operation //FunctionTwo) : 1.88 sec

**benchmark #2:**

- times called: 1'000'000
- input: 2000 characters
- duration (string operations): 27.69 sec
- duration (regex operations): 41.436 sec

**Conclusion: String operations will almost always beat regular expressions, if programmed efficiently. But the more complex it gets, the harder it will be that string operations can keep up not only in performance matters but also regarding maintenance.**

**Code FunctionOne**

```java
private void FunctionOne(string input) {
    var matches = new List<string>();
    var match = new StringBuilder();
    Boolean startRecording = false;
    foreach( char c in input) {
        if (c.Equals('<')) {
            startRecording = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (c.Equals('>')) {
            matches.Add(match.ToString());
            match = new StringBuilder();
            startRecording = false;
        }

        if (startRecording) {
            match.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

**Code FunctionTwo**

```java
Regex regx = new Regex("<.*?>");
private void FunctionTwo(string input) {
    Match m = regx.Match(input);
    var results = new List<string>();
    while (m.Success) {
        results.Add(m.Value);
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual answer is that it heavily depends what you're doing, how, and how often

Comment: Your regex benchmark is very wrong; you're re-compiling the regex every time.  If you reuse a single instance, it will become much faster.  If you pass `RegexOptions.Compiled`, it will become even faster.

Comment: Ok Thanks SLaks, I will post my new results here.

Comment: Your string code is also very wrong; you're throwing away large numbers of string instances.  You can make it much faster using a StringBuilder.  (and probably also by tracking indices and concatenating ranges)

Comment: Also, C# has character literals: `'<'`.

Comment: I think you got mixed up here. The code describing what operations you want to perform should be in the question rather than the answer.

Comment: I thought it's a good way to have benchmarks to illustrate the difference between regular expressions. Thanks for helping me out, guys!

Comment: It's really a non question. Ask and answer a question if you are going to provide useful insight that can't be found elsewhere. This question is rather pointless, in my view.

Comment: @David: No. I wanted to answer my own question. I did not want to perform anything specifically, really.

Comment: I disagree that string operations will always be faster than Regex. A regex, when compiled, becomes a super specialized and optimized .NET function which will likely beat the string operation by a fair margin. For example, I've found that a compiled Regex is faster than a `IndexOf` call.

Comment: @JulianR: I don't think that's always true, although I have no evidence to support either possibility.

Comment: However, it would be very interesting to see the performance of a compiled regex here.

Comment: Also, `[^>]*` would probably be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I did some profiling in C# a while back, comparing the following:

1)LINQ to Objects.

2)Lambda Expressions.

3)Traditional iterative method.

All 3 methods were tested both with and without Regular Expressions.
The conclusion in my test case was clear that Regular Expressions are quite a bit slower than non-Regex in all 3 cases when searching for strings in a large amount of text.

You can read the details on my blog:
http://www.midniteblog.com/?p=72