# How can I remove numbers/digits from strings in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of strings:

```
List<string> _words = ExtractWords(strippedHtml);
```

`_words` contains 1799 indexes; in each index there is a string.

Some of the strings contain only numbers, for example:

`" 2"` or `"2013"`

I want to remove these strings and so in the end the List will contain only strings with letters and not digits.

A string like `"001hello"` is OK but `"001"` is not OK and should be removed.

Comment: Create a small method that converts the `string` to a `char[] array` then if the index contains a number replace it with `""`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ for that:

```
_words = _words.Where(w => w.Any(c => !Char.IsDigit(c))).ToList();
```

This would filter out strings that consist entirely of digits, along with empty strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
_words = _words.Where(w => !w.All(char.IsDigit))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: In general, `Any()` is preferred to `!All()` because Any can stop evaluating after the first non-match, whereas All has to evaluate every member of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

For removing words that are only made of digits *and* whitespace:

```
var good = new List<string>();
var _regex = new Regex(@"^[\d\s]*$");
foreach (var s in _words) {
    if (!_regex.Match(s).Success)
        good.Add(s);
}
```

If you want to use LINQ something like this should do:

```
_words = _words.Where(w => w.Any(c => !char.IsDigit(c) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: IMO, regex is an overkill for this (small words)

Comment: Depends on the definition of overkill. This is faster than LINQ.

Comment: All those... keystrokes... will be lost in time, like tears... in... rain

Answer (score 1):

You can use a traditional `foreach` and `Integer.TryParse` to detect numbers.
This will be faster than Regex or LINQ.

```
var stringsWithoutNumbers = new List<string>();
foreach (var str in _words)
{
    int n;
    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(str, out n);
    if (!isNumeric)
    {
        stringsWithoutNumbers.Add(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution, if it doesn't need to eliminate words like `"1 2"`.

Comment: @ctn: Good point. If there can be strings as you pointed out (with blanks in between), then a regex might indeed be the better approach.

Comment: Have you done performance testing on this? I suspect you're right that's it's faster, but I wanted to know if you made sure.

Comment: @neontapir: To be honest, I haven't. But since there is no action that costs much time, I'm pretty confident this is the fastest way of how to do this.
If you wish I can set up a test and let you know the differences.
Else you can also have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638637/whats-faster-regex-or-string-operations

Comment: Shaved off 60 ms by using `_regex.IsMatch(s)`: https://gist.github.com/perses/5878819. I'll stop now :)