# Speed up matching strings python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary

I have 2 different Dataframes for which I am trying to match strings columns (names)

Below are just some sample of DF's

```
df1 (127000,3)
Code     Name     PostalCode
150      Maarc    47111
250      Kirc     41111
170      Moic     42111
140      Nirc     44111
550      Lacter   47111

df2 (38000,3)
Code     NAME     POSTAL_CODE
150      Marc     47111
250      Kikc     41111
170      Mosc     49111
140      NiKc     44111
550      Lacter   47111
```

The aim is to create another DF3 as shown below

```
Code     NAME    Best Match   Score
150      Marc    Maarc        0.9
250      Karc    Kirc         0.9
```

The following code gives the expected output

```
import difflib
from functools import partial
f = partial(difflib.get_close_matches, possibilities= df1['Name'].tolist(), n=1)

matches = df2['NAME'].map(f).str[0].fillna('')

scores = [difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).ratio()
          for x, y in zip(matches, df2['NAME'])]

df3 = df2.assign(best=matches, score=scores)
df3.sort_values(by='score')
```

**The problem**

To match those strings for only 2 rows it takes around 30sec. This task has to be done for 1K rows which will take hours!

**The Question**

How can I speed up the code?
I was thinking about something like fetchall?

**EDIT**

Even the fuzzywuzzy libraries has been tried, which takes longer than difflib with the following code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def get_fuzz(df, w):
    s = df['Name'].apply(lambda y: fuzz.token_set_ratio(y, w))
    idx = s.idxmax()
    return {'Name': df['Name'].iloc[idx], 'CODE': df['Code'].iloc[idx], 'Value': s.max()}

df2['NAME'].apply(lambda x: get_fuzz(df1, x))

df2 = df2.assign(search= df2['NAME'].apply(lambda x: get_fuzz(df1, x)))
```

Comment: unfortunately I don’t think difflib is the right tool for this task, it’s not that fast

Comment: Maybe you can try building a distance matrix or something like that using the `sklearn` module. For your case the levenshtein distance may be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to speed up the matching step by using the postal code column as discriminant. I was able to goes from 1h40 to 7mn of computation.

Below are just some sample of DF's

```
df1 (127000,3)
Code     Name     PostalCode
150      Maarc    47111
250      Kirc     41111
170      Moic     42111
140      Nirc     44111
550      Lacter   47111

df2 (38000,3)
Code     NAME     POSTAL_CODE
150      Marc     47111
250      Kikc     41111
170      Mosc     49111
140      NiKc     44111
550      Lacter   47111
```

And below is the code that matches the Name column and retrieve the name with the best score

```
%%time
import difflib
from functools import partial

def difflib_match (df1, df2, set_nan = True):

    # Fill NaN
    df2['best']= np.nan
    df2['score']= np.nan

    # Apply function to retrieve unique first letter of Name's column
    first= df2['POSTAL_CODE'].unique()

    # Loop over each first letter to apply the matching by starting with the same Postal code for both DF
    for m, letter in enumerate(first):

        # IF Divid by 100, print Unique values processed 
        if m%100 == 0:
            print(m, 'of', len(first))

        df1_first= df1[df1['PostalCode'] == letter]
        df2_first= df2[df2['POSTAL_CODE'] == letter]

        # Function to match using the Name column from the Web                   
        f = partial(difflib.get_close_matches, possibilities= df1_first['Name'].tolist(), n=1) 

        # Define which columns to compare while mapping with first letter
        matches = df2_first['NAME'].map(f).str[0].fillna('')

        # Retrieve the best score for each match
        scores = [difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).ratio()
              for x, y in zip(matches, df2_first['NAME'])]

        # Assign the result to the DF
        for i, name in enumerate(df2_first['NAME']):
            df2['best'].where(df2['NAME'] != name, matches.iloc[i], inplace = True)
            df2['score'].where(df2['NAME'] != name, scores[i], inplace = True)

    return df2

# Apply Function
df_diff= difflib_match(df1, df2)

# Display DF
print('Shape: ', df_diff.shape)
df_diff.head()
```

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way I can think of matching string is using Regex.

It's a search language design to find matches in a string.

You can see a example here:

```
import re

txt = "The rain in Spain"
x = re.search("^The.*Spain$", txt)

//Outputs: x == true
```

*Taken from: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Since I don't understand anything Dataframe, I don't know how to implement Regex in your code, but I hope that Regex function might help you.

Comment: Why do you think regex will be faster than literal matching?

Comment: It's up for debate, but it usually depends on the complexity of the match and how well you can write your Regex as you can see in the following links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638637/whats-faster-regex-or-string-operations/16638638

https://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/