# When should we use Pattern and Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

I came across a question today and the question was:

Suppose I want to find total number of occurrences of following substring:

```
Any substring that starts with 1 followed by any(0 or more) number of 0's 
and then followed by 1.
```

I solved this question in two ways:

**Method 1**

I formed a regular expression for it: `1[0]*1` and used the `Pattern` and `Matcher` class to solve the problem.

**Method 2**

I traversed the string and incrementing counter whenever pattern was matched.

My question is why my first method is **extremely inefficient** as compared to my second method. I thought that inbuilt functions are more efficient to use.Turns out this does not happen in all cases.The time gap is really big.

Here is the proof:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Pat_mat
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     String str="111011010000001011";
     Pattern p=Pattern.compile("10*(?=1)");
     Matcher matcher=p.matcher(str);
     int s=0,i;
     long st=System.nanoTime();
     while(matcher.find())
      ++s;
     long ft=System.nanoTime()-st;      
     System.out.println("time taken by inbuilt fn "+ft);
     System.out.println("output: "+s);
     s=0;i=0;
     st=System.nanoTime();
     while(i<str.length())
     {
         if(str.charAt(i)!='1')
          {++i;continue;}
         else
         {
             if(i+1<str.length()&&str.charAt(i+1)=='1')
              ++s;
             else if(i+1<str.length()&&str.charAt(i+1)=='0')
              {while(i+1<str.length()&&str.charAt(i+1)=='0')
               ++i;               
             if((i+1)<str.length()&&str.charAt(i+1)=='1')
              ++s;}
         }
         ++i;
     }     
     ft=System.nanoTime()-st; 
     System.out.println("time taken by my way "+ft);
     System.out.println("output: "+s);
 }
}
```

Comment: The inefficiency is probably due to backtracking.

Comment: *I thought that inbuilt functions are more efficient to use.* Why? Using a regex for a very specific issue, like this one, will be slower indeed, because a regex should work with all kinds of complex patterns.

Comment: You can boost your regex performance by using a possessive quantifier: `p=Pattern.compile("10*+(?=1)")`, but [it will still lose](http://ideone.com/AImmkl) to a non-regex approach. Use non-regex based solutions where possible. It is a rule of thumb.

Comment: Does removing `[]` around `0` help?

Comment: You should read this :http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122440/how-do-regular-expressions-actually-work

Comment: @Manu i would expect that state machine which is build shouls be less or more optimized for required use case.

Comment: Also worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667015/is-regex-too-slow-real-life-examples-where-simple-non-regex-alternative-is-bett