# java8 regex match very slow

Tags: java, regex, string, performance

i have a regex `^[a-z]+([a-z0-9-]+)*[a-z0-9]+$` for validation.

```
String src = "alfjaldfjaldmflajdflakclaldkfjaldjlad,fl.adc.aldjfal";
src.matches("^[a-z]+([a-z0-9-]+)*[a-z0-9]+$");
```

but, matches is not respond. 
do you know fast regex??

Comment: You are using greedy matchers which are - turns out - slow. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667015/is-regex-too-slow-real-life-examples-where-simple-non-regex-alternative-is-bett) for more information.

Comment: @Lino Precompiled regexps are typically pretty fast.  This one here may require quite a bit of backtracking which is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Just elaborating on the answer provided by @OldCurmudgeon

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$");
String src = "alfjaldfjaldmflajdflakclaldkfjaldjlad,fl.adc.aldjfal";
long start = System.nanoTime();
src.matches("^[a-z]+([a-z0-9-]+)*[a-z0-9]+$");
long end1 = System.nanoTime();
src.matches("^[a-z]+[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+$");
long end2 = System.nanoTime();
src.matches("^[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$");
long end3 = System.nanoTime();
pattern.matcher(src).matches();
long end4 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println((end1 - start)/1000);
System.out.println((end2 - end1)/1000);
System.out.println((end3 - end2)/1000);
System.out.println((end4 - end3)/1000);
```

output in microseconds

```
14377
1130
190
112
```

and the following non regex method takes just 10 micro seconds.

```
private static boolean matches(String str)
{
    if (str.length() < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char first = str.charAt(0);
    if (!(first >= 'a' && first <= 'z'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    char last = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
    if (!(last >= 'a' && last <= 'z') && !(last >= '0' && last <= '9'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i + 1);
        if (!(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') && !(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') && ch != '-')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here: `([a-z0-9-]+)*`

You are trying to match *one or more x 0 or more times*. This does not make sense.

Try instead just `([a-z0-9-]+)` or `([a-z0-9-]*)` whichever is correct for your requirements.

Also - you can compile patterns using:

```
Pattern compiled = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

This can help but is not your problem.

Comment: `([a-z0-9-]+)*` should be changed into `([a-z0-9-]*)` and not `([a-z0-9-]+)`, but +1 anyway! By doing so you impose that that character class `[a-z0-9-]` exists at least once, what was not the case before!

Comment: first and third part can also be simplified. the regex can be ^[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$ note there is no + in the first and third part as that is any way taken care of by the second part.