# Regex.Replace does not timeout and throw

Tags: c#, regex, unit-testing

I need to test that a regex replacement times out. I'm using [this overload](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0a591d03feb4da2574d2304b4fde332dcba7b37e/src/libraries/System.Text.RegularExpressions/src/System/Text/RegularExpressions/Regex.Replace.cs#L30):

```cs
public static string Replace(
  string input, string pattern, string replacement, 
  RegexOptions options,
  TimeSpan matchTimeout
)
```

My code doesn't throw on timeout, so I decided to test the actual framework method:

```cs
[Fact]
public void framework_method_should_throw() {

  var input       = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0,100).Select(x => "01234567890123456789"));
  var pattern     = "3[abc4]5(?!xyz)[abc6]7[abc8]9";
  var replacement = "bar";
  var timeout     = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);   // <--- should time out immediately

  Action action = () => Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.None, timeout);

  action.Should().Throw<RegexMatchTimeoutException>();
}
```

I used a massive search string, and various difficult patterns (the one above is just an example), but it never throws.

> Expected a <System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexMatchTimeoutException> to be thrown, but no exception was thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE

No this is not a dupe of that [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616435/how-do-i-timeout-regex-operations-to-prevent-hanging-in-net-4-5). Firstly that is for .NET framework (10+ years old) whereas this is for .NET Core (v6). Secondly that has a different API! I know how to use the timeouts, I didn't know how to force it to work. The guy that closed the question did not even know the difference between .NET Framework and .NET Core!

Comment: Why do you think it should? It is just faster than you think it is. If you run it in a simple console app you will see that it matches / replaces the string quite nicely - probably in way under 1 ms, which is really quite a long time in this regard. This is of course subjective and depends on many factors of your environment. (Unit) tests with expected timing are not really a good idea. To many unreliable factors can count in and make the test flaky. (For exemplary purposes you can try to use `TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)`)

Comment: @Christian.K Agreed. But my intention is not to test timing precisely - I just want to know that it **can** time out - I want to force a failure. I assumed there was something wrong with my code, but maybe the regex engine is just crazy fast.

Comment: There are regexes floating around the web that do take a very long time to execute. Try looking around. I found this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667015/is-regex-too-slow-real-life-examples-where-simple-non-regex-alternative-is-bett

Comment: @Ionix , I've just run your code using .FromTicks(1) instead and it does indeed timeout.

Comment: Well it is fast :-) (even [faster](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/regular-expression-improvements-in-dotnet-7/) in .NET 7 if the regex pattern is a const string, due to source generation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-system-timespan)) (emphasis mine):

> The `matchTimeout` parameter specifies how long a pattern matching method should try to find a match before it times out. **Setting a time-out interval prevents regular expressions that rely on excessive backtracking from appearing to "stop responding when they process input that contains near matches.** For more information, see [Best Practices for Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices) and [Backtracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions). If no match is found in that time interval, the method throws a [RegexMatchTimeoutException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexmatchtimeoutexception?view=net-6.0) exception. matchTimeout overrides any default time-out value defined for the application domain in which the method executes.

The easiest way to test this is to use a pattern that's vulnerable to [Catastrophic Backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Here's an example that will throw a `RegexMatchTimeoutException`:

```
string input = "This is a test string that should not match.";
string pattern = @"^(\w+\s?)*$";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty, 
                              RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

Comment: i just tried that pattern on a modern spec machine, and it eats through that pattern like it's nothing. I think the best option is the `FromTicks(1)` approach mentioned above. But you taught me something new though, so thanks again!

Comment: @lonix That was just a simple demo example. The thing about Catastrophic Backtracking is that the number of steps grows exponentially with the number of characters in the string. For example, try with `input = new string('a', 1000) + ".";` and good luck having any modern-spec machine run through it without timing out or halting :)

Comment: Yeah that brought my machine to it's knees - I could hear the gears crunching!

Answer (score 0):

I increased the search space dramatically - by changing the above code to `Enumerable.Range(0,10_000)`. Only then did it timeout.

I automatically assumed a bug in my code, but it turns out the .NET regex engine is EXTREMELY performant!

Another approach mentioned above by @ChristianK is to use `TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)` instead. And, incredibly, perf will increase even more in [.net7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/regular-expression-improvements-in-dotnet-7/).

Comment: One thing to note though: in a year, try those settings on a newer faster machine, and the test will probably fail again. So you'd need to increase the search string, etc. Not a great option, but works for now.